# Implementing WhenAll on QueueBackgroundWorkItem

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I need to spawn some long running tasks in ASP.NET WebAPI, and I chose to do that using `QueueBackgroundWorkItem`.

My question is -

I need to implement a `WhenAll` mechanism with those tasks, meaning - I need to know when some tasks has finished, and then to perform some other task.

How can that be done using `QueueBackgroundWorkItem`? I couldn't find a way to do that, since it returns `void`, and accepts `Action`.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to wait for the tasks (even asynchronously), why do you want to use `QueueBackgroundWorkItem` instead of `Task.Run`?

Comment: Because Task.Run will not register with the ASP.NET, and therefore will be shut down in case of app pool recycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [TaskCompletionSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174(v=vs.110).aspx) to create a helper method like this:

```
public static Task RunViaQueueBackgroundWorkItem(Action<CancellationToken> action)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<int> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
    HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem((ct) =>
    {
        try
        {
            action(ct);

            if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                tcs.TrySetCanceled();
            else
                tcs.TrySetResult(0);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            tcs.TrySetException(ex);
        }
    });

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

This method will return a task that will complete after the action completes. Note that it handles the case where an exception occurs during the invocation of the action. It also handles the case if cancellation is requested.

Here is an example of how you can use it:

```
public async Task<string> Get(int id)
{
    var t1 = RunViaQueueBackgroundWorkItem(ct => DoSomeTask1(ct));
    var t2 = RunViaQueueBackgroundWorkItem(ct => DoSomeTask2(ct));

    await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);

    //...
}
```

For completeness, here is the helper method for the other overload of `QueueBackgroundWorkItem`:

```
public static Task RunViaQueueBackgroundWorkItem(Func<CancellationToken,Task> asyncAction)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<int> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
    HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(async (ct) => 
    {
        try
        {
            await asyncAction(ct);

            if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                tcs.TrySetCanceled();
            else
                tcs.TrySetResult(0);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            tcs.TrySetException(ex);
        }
    });

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: What would you do different if you had a async method using the `QueueBackgroundWorkItem(Func<CancellationToken, Task>)`  overload?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, I updated the answer to include it.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to implement a WhenAll mechanism with those tasks, meaning - I need to know when some tasks has finished, and then to perform some other task.

What you should do is write up the logic you need:

```
async Task MyWorkAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
  var t1 = Work1Async(token);
  var t2 = Work2Async(token);
  await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);
  ... // More work
}
```

And then just call `QueueBackgroundWorkItem` once:

```
HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(token => MyWorkAsync(token));
```

Comment: I think that will defeat the whole purpose of QueueBackgroundWorkItem. I don't want to create new Task in a QueueBackgroundWorkItem call, since this task will not register in the ASP.NET engine.

Comment: @ml123: I'm not sure what you're saying; the code example I provided *will* register `MyWorkAsync` with ASP.NET. IMO it's more idiomatic than trying to wait on QBWI work, because QBWI is specifically for fire-and-forget work. If you want to do a `Task.WhenAll` on the results, then that's not fire-and-forget.

Comment: Yes, `MyWorkAsync` will register, but the tasks created in `Work1Async` and `Work2Async` will not.

Comment: @ml123: That doesn't matter, because `MyWorkAsync` won't complete until both `Work1Async` and `Work2Async` complete.